# can i see the built in java codes of algorithms in WEKA through eclipse or anything else?

Tags: eclipse, algorithm, weka

I want to see the built in code of say, Naive Bayes or J48 algorithms in WEKA, is that possible?

In order to get the result from one algorithm & apply it as another one's input,i need to understand the code at first and want to change it for my purpose in eclipse.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### Where can I get WEKA's source code?
>
> Every WEKA release comes with a jar archive (this is just a simple ZIP archive) that contains the complete sources. It is called `weka-src.jar`. Alternatively, you can get WEKA's source code also from [Subversion](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Subversion).

From [the WEKA FAQ](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Where+can+I+get+WEKA%27s+source+code%3F) via [Google.](https://www.google.com/search?q=weka%20source%20code)